# How can I save my chat log or chat history in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I would like to save my chat logs, or my chat history, for archival purposes. Most chat clients that I use already have a logging function of some kind.

Does the Diablo 3 game client save the chat session anywhere on the drive?

Comment: Hi, Calculemus.  I removed the section asking for third party tools to prevent close votes; we don't allow questions asking us for software recommendations.  Hopefully you still get an answer that can help you!

Comment: Point of clarification, but it appears from conversation on http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge that *mods* of the original game may not be classed as third party *tools*. It might be possible that there is now a new answer to this question which would possibly make it not a duplicate (if it were edited to say *mods*), that is: the answer to the question might be different now (new mod available) than it was four months ago. I'd be interested in other people's opinions here.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen, I highly doubt it... if you modify the original game and try to jump online, it's probably not going to let you. WoW supported mossing, Diablo didnt.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen Asking for mods is a straight up off-topic question.  Answers to the duplicate can recommend mods, but a question can't specifically ask for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client itself does not appear to offer any chat logging (or at least, as far as my experience, and the mods attending to similar questions on blizzards forums go).

If you are just needing to remember something, rather then needing an actual text-based log of all communication, a recommendation would be to just take screenshots. It should save in a user directory somewhere.